# Deploy and Run automation code using selenium web driver in Java

Tags: selenium, webdriver, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I am writing Automation code in Selenium Webdriver using Java in Eclipse IDE.
My project uses TestNG framework in POM design Patttern ,Bit Bucket repository,
How do I biuld and run automation test overnight.?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You can configure any CI server like jenkins, etc to fetch the code from bit bucket and run it periodically.

Answer (score 1):

As @aolisa mentioned there are several tools for continuous integration (CI), that You could use. 
When I've started to create somekind of CI like You, I've installed Jenkins locally and started to playing with it.

My opinion is that this good entry point is Jenkins.

Here is nice article to start off for Jenkins: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Jenkins/article.html

For Jenkins to start, here are few steps:

1. install it (https://jenkins.io/),
2. login to Jenkins,
3. create job (Maven),
4. connect to Your git repository (in your case BitBucket),
5. use maven commands to manipulate with tests,
6. play...tweak... maintain... :)

But in this answers nobody mentioned cloud CI which are really good today.

Now You have several services, but I've tested this ones, and are really easy to use, and documentaion is really straight-forward, and important is that You can play for a while because they are free (to a point) so check them out:

1. http://circleci.com/
2. https://www.bitrise.io/

Hope this help...